# Applying a function to all column combination pairs and extracting the pvalues

Tags: r

I have some data which looks like:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 8
   XGB       Logistic  NN        NNDeep    RandomForest SVM       SVMLinear LightGBM 
   <fct>     <fct>     <fct>     <fct>     <fct>        <fct>     <fct>     <fct>    
 1 Incorrect Incorrect Incorrect Incorrect Incorrect    Incorrect Incorrect Incorrect
 2 Correct   Correct   Correct   Correct   Correct      Correct   Correct   Correct  
 3 Correct   Correct   Correct   Correct   Correct      Correct   Correct   Correct  
 4 Correct   Correct   Correct   Correct   Correct      Correct   Correct   Correct  
 5 Correct   Correct   Correct   Correct   Correct      Correct   Correct   Correct  
 6 Correct   Correct   Correct   Correct   Correct      Correct   Correct   Correct  
 7 Incorrect Correct   Correct   Correct   Correct      Correct   Correct   Incorrect
 8 Incorrect Correct   Correct   Correct   Correct      Correct   Correct   Correct  
 9 Correct   Correct   Correct   Correct   Correct      Correct   Correct   Correct  
10 Correct   Correct   Correct   Correct   Correct      Correct   Correct   Correct
```

I can do something like:

```
mcnemar.test(allCorrectIncorrectResults$XGB, allCorrectIncorrectResults$Logistic)$p.value
```

However, I would like to apply the same function to all combinations of the columns. I tried the following without luck.

```
combn(allCorrectIncorrectResults, 2, function(x){
  mcnemar.test(allCorrectIncorrectResults[x[1], ],
               allCorrectIncorrectResults[x[2], ],
               correct = TRUE)$p.value})
```

I would like to report the results in matrix something similar to:

```
          XGB       Logistic    ...   LightGBM

XGB        NA         pval      ...   pval
Logistic  pval         NA       ...   pval
...
LightGBM  pval        pval      ...   NA
```

Data

```
d <- structure(list(XGB = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Correct", "Incorrect"), class = "factor"), 
    Logistic = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), .Label = c("Correct", "Incorrect"), class = "factor"), 
    NN = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Correct", 
    "Incorrect"), class = "factor"), NNDeep = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Correct", 
    "Incorrect"), class = "factor"), RandomForest = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Correct", 
    "Incorrect"), class = "factor"), SVM = structure(c(2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Correct", "Incorrect"
    ), class = "factor"), SVMLinear = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Correct", "Incorrect"
    ), class = "factor"), LightGBM = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Correct", "Incorrect"
    ), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can use `combn` like below

```
out <- matrix(NA,nrow = ncol(d),ncol = ncol(d))
out[lower.tri(out)] <- combn(d, 2, function(x){
  mcnemar.test(x[[1]],
               x[[2]],
               correct = TRUE)$p.value}, simplify = T)

out[upper.tri(out)] <- t(out)[upper.tri(t(out))]
out
```

where `combn` choose two columns from `d` as the arguments `x` passed to `mcnemar.test`

Then, we will get

```
> out
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7] [,8]
[1,]        NA 0.4795001 0.4795001 0.4795001 0.4795001 0.4795001 0.4795001    1
[2,] 0.4795001        NA       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN    1
[3,] 0.4795001       NaN        NA       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN    1
[4,] 0.4795001       NaN       NaN        NA       NaN       NaN       NaN    1
[5,] 0.4795001       NaN       NaN       NaN        NA       NaN       NaN    1
[6,] 0.4795001       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN        NA       NaN    1
[7,] 0.4795001       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN        NA    1
[8,] 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000   NA
```